# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided (ExpressJs & nunjucks)

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

I am trying to use nunjucks templating engine with Expres js. The page is rendered correctly but error appears  on console.
`Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`

### from  [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html) docs

```
var app = express();

nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

I traced the error and found it comes form `at new NunjucksView (C:\Users\future\Desktop\New folder (2)\node_modules\nunjucks\src\express-app.js:13:13)`

In `nodemodules/nunjucks/src/express-app.js` throw error

```
    if (!this.ext && !this.defaultEngine) {
      throw new Error('No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.');
    }
```

Which means as I understand that defaultEngine is not set.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/elhaw/nunjucks-demo)

---

***How to***  set default template engine while using  nunjucks.

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#express ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the default `view engine` for express to be the same extension known/rendered by `nunjucks`

```
const express =  require('express');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

const app = express();

// set default express engine and extension
app.engine('html', nunjucks.render);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// configure nunjucks engine
nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(9090, () => {
  console.log('http://localhost:9090')
});
```

if you want to change templates/views extension, you can change it like that:

```
app.engine('nunj', nunjucks.render);
app.set('view engine', 'nunj');
```

and then rename your templates/views `index.nunj`

Comment: It works. But it throw `Error: template not found: error.html`. I added error.html file in view directory and error is fixed.@Ahmed Ayoub

_I did not try changing  templates/views extension._